# How to submit button with ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a form data which contained some empty inputs filed and a submit button.I retrive that form with ajax call.Ajax it's correctly for me and working well and form data cames to my web interface.I just want to make some inserts after retriving form data BUT when i click button doesn't work and button doesn't make any action.

My form data which retrive with ajax:pagination_parser.php

```
<form  class="form" method="post" action='#'>
        <select name="f_practical" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="si">Si</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
        <button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' type='submit' value='submit' name='form2'><i class='ace-icon fa  fa-check icon-only bigger-110'></i></button>
</form>
```

MY Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $('#operator_disactiv_click').click(function(e) {// when a div is clicked my form cames to the interface            
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
              url: "pagination_parser.php",
              timeout: 30000,
              cache: false,
              error: function(){
                    $("#op_disactiv").hide().html('server not responding');
                },
                success: function( msg ) {
                        $("#op_disactiv").html(msg);
                }
        });

    });
</script>
```

PHP CODE which doesn't work for me:

```
if (!empty($_POST['form2'])) {// 

  $query="insert into..... etc";
   }
```

Comment: Why would adding or removing classes affect the form data in any way? Are you really just trying to change the values ?

Comment: Also, you're not sending any data in that ajax call ?

Comment: And not a single selector in the JS matches anything in the HTML ?

Comment: Where is the listener to that input button?

Comment: This code is the basic idea which describe my problem,surly i cant write the whole code here,I just want to make insert into Db with this inputs field.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether  it's your whole/real code or not, you still [should provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

First be clear whether to submit the form using normal way or the Ajax way.
If you want Ajax form submission, it is not suggested to write

```
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' type='submit' value='submit' name='form2'>
```

instead code

```
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' type='button' value='submit' id="submit_button" name='form2'>
```

i.e., Submit [type='submit'] should be Button[type='button']
so that the form is submitted through ajax call and not through usual form submission and you can pass your data through

```
data: $('formid').serialize(),
```

or by passing individual values with the help of their ids

PS.. You should instantiate your form submission by 'onclick function' after clicking the button id="submit_button"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass form values to php code, try following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form').submit(function(e) {// when a div is clicked my form cames to the interface            
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
              url: "pagination_parser.php",
              timeout: 30000,
              data : $('.form').serialize(),
              cache: false,
              error: function(){
                    $("#op_disactiv").hide().html('server not responding');
                },
                success: function( msg ) {
                        $("#op_disactiv").html(msg);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

then check if you are getting values on php file

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
/*---run your php code here-----------*/
?>
```

Comment: $('.form').submit(function(e) { }// i can't create a function like that,because i want that my form retrived when a specific div is clicked .